# show the last x records in a query

Tags: crystal-reports

What im trying to do is show the last say 2 million records as when the query runs it looks through 6-7 million records and the data im trying to look at is right at the end not sure if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Group Sort Expert** to select Top/Bottom N records (N of your choosing) or the Top / Bottom percentage of a group.

Though I would generally try refine my parameters to pull out the relevant data, rather than "trimming" the returned data.